# Best strategy to revert faulty asp.net deployment

Tags: asp.net, iis, visual-studio-2013, web-deployment

Currently I package my changes using the publish wizard in Visual Studio and take those files to the server and run the deploy batch file in command line.

What is the best strategy to use if I have issues in the deployment and I want to revert back my website/service to the last working state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your deployment is a manual process, it would probably be best to create a backup zip or copy of the webroot - this could be added as a command in your batch file before the other commands.

Alternatively, you could create a label in your source control system each time you deploy which would give you the ability to re-deploy a previous version.  I would only advise this approach though if you have some sort of CI process in place to guarantee that the label is done prior to each deployment/release, otherwise your process is dependent on the person deploying remembering to create that label - if they forget, then you can't restore that previous version.